# JQuery UI Sortable - on sortchange get new index or id attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So I have an unordered list. I have features to use sortable but now I want to use sortchange for another feature.

```
<ul class="sortable>
    <li id="id_of_object">blablabla>
        <input type="hidden" class="tipo_of_object"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`id_of_object` is a number and `tipo_of_object` is a string. These are just placeholders for this question. Keep that in mind!

I have this:

```
$('.sortable').on('sortchange',function(event,ui){
    var idOld = ui.item.attr('id'); <-- This is the item being dragged
    var idNew = <-- I want this one! the one being comtemplated to be dropped.

    alert(idNew);
});
```

Keep in mind I don't want the value when dropped. I want to see the id of the one item when it changes.

I hope I got what I wanted through to you guys. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

May be this:

```
var itemIDs = [];
$('.sortable').on('sortstart', function () {
  itemIDs = $('.sortable').sortable('toArray');
});
$('.sortable').on('sortchange', function (event, ui) {
  var idOld = ui.item.attr('id');
  for (var i = 0; i < itemIDs.length; i++) {
    if (idOld == itemIDs[i]) {
       itemIDs = $('.sortable').sortable('toArray');
       var idNew = itemIDs[i]; // your new id
       alert(idNew);
       break;
    }
  }
});
```

Note: You may need to use parseInt() function to make sure it does not compare int to string in the if statement.